# pocketsphinx voice recognition - install gconf

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, pocketsphinx, gstreamer-0.10

I am using a ubuntu 14.04 and just recently installed the pocketsphinx package. When I try to run the sample robocup.launch file, I get an error saying gconfaudiosrc is no element. Hence when i try sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-gconf, I get the following error:

E: Unable to locate package gstreamer0.10-gconf

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer0.10-gconf'

Any sugesstions on what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stuck with the same issue, I solved it by downloading the deb file from here : https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/sound/gstreamer0.10-gconf

And then installing it by :

sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file

followed by

sudo apt-get install -f